# how to clear previous form fields when switching bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i have three bootstrap tabs and each of them has form fields, if i go to other tab then i want to clear the fields(if they are filled) which was on last tab.
For exmaple:
if I am on shared space tab and filled the form fields then when I switch to other private space or meeting room tab Shared space fields should clear.

here is my view.blade.php file

```
<div class="form-group">
                Space Type: 
                    <select class="select-tabs" onchange="doChange()" id='spaceType' name="spaceType" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <option  disabled>Select</option>
                            <option data-target="#sharedSpace" {{$list->spaceType == "shared space" ?  "selected" : false}} value = "shared space">Shared Space</option>
                            <option data-target="#privateSpace" {{$list->spaceType == "private space" ? "selected" : false}} value = "private space">Private Space</option>
                            <option data-target="#meetingRoom" {{$list->spaceType == "meeting room" ?  "selected" : false}} value = "meeting room">Meeting Room</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
<div class="tab-content">
                <div id="sharedSpace" class="tab-pane">
                    <div>
                        {{Form::label('totalSeats', 'Total Seats: ')}}
                        {{Form::text('totalSeats', $list->totalSeats, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'e.g: Rs. 10000', 'type' => 'number'])}}
                        <br>
                        <div id="textArea-fields" class="form-group">
                                <label id="labelTwo" for="description">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="write here...">{{(isset($list->description)) ? $list->description : ""}}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <h1>Features</h1>                 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="privateSpace" class="tab-pane">
                    <div>
                        {{Form::label('totalOffices', 'Total Offices: ')}}
                        {{Form::text('totalOffices', $list->totalOffices, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'e.g: Rs. 10000', 'type' => 'number'])}}
                        <br>
                        {{Form::label('availableOffices', 'Available Offices: ')}}
                        {{Form::text('availableOffices', $list->availableOffices, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'e.g: Rs. 10000', 'type' => 'number'])}}
                        <br>
                        <div id="textArea-fields" class="form-group">
                                <label id="labelTwo" for="description">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="write here...">{{(isset($list->description)) ? $list->description : ""}}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>    
                        <h1>Features</h1>                    
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[5]', 'whiteBoard', (array_key_exists(5, $list->feature)) ? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('whiteBoard', 'White board')}}
                        <br>
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[6]', 'cabinets/lockers', (array_key_exists(6, $list->feature))? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('cabinets/lockers', 'Cabinets/Lockers')}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="meetingRoom" class="tab-pane">
                    <div>
                        {{Form::label('totalRooms', 'Total Rooms: ')}}
                        {{Form::text('totalRooms', $list->totalRooms, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'e.g: Rs. 10000', 'type' => 'number'])}}
                        <br>
                        <div id="textArea-fields" class="form-group">
                                <label id="labelTwo" for="description">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="write here...">{{(isset($list->description)) ? $list->description : ""}}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <h1>Features</h1>                            
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[0]', 'videoConference', (array_key_exists(0, $list->feature)) ? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('videoConference', 'Video conference')}}
                        <br>
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[1]', 'projector', (array_key_exists(1, $list->feature))? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('projector', 'Projector')}}
                        <br>
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[2]', 'whiteBoard', (array_key_exists(2, $list->feature)) ? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('whiteBoard', 'White board')}}
                        <br>
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[3]', 'micFacility', (array_key_exists(3, $list->feature)) ? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('micFacility', 'Mic facility')}}
                        <br>
                        {{Form::checkbox('feature[4]', 'conferenceTable', (array_key_exists(4, $list->feature)) ? true : false)}}
                        {{Form::label('conferenceTable', 'Conference table')}}
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

and here is edit.js file for changing tab:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var something = document.getElementById("spaceType");
    var val = something.options[something.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val == 'private space') {
       $(':selected', this).tab('show');
    }
    if (val == 'meeting room') {
       $(':selected', this).tab('show');
    }
    if (val == 'private space') {
       $(':selected', this).tab('show');
    }
   $(".select-tabs").on('change', function () {
       $(':selected', this).tab('show');
    });
 });
```

sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery UI, we just find the selector with the ID.

if you think this is possible for you, then you could use jQuery as follows:

```
$('#spaceType').on('change', function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                    var space_type = e.target.value; //we get the value of the select so we can compare it later

                   //You can add as many switch cases as you want to make it work
                    switch(space_type) { //depending on selection then you'll call a function to clear the div.
                        case "private space":
                            clearForm($("#sharedSpace"));
                            clearForm($("#meetingRoom"));

                            break;
                        case "meeting room":
                            clearForm($("#privateSpace"));
                            clearForm($("#sharedSpace"));
                            break;
                        default:
                            clearForm($("#privateSpace"));
                            clearForm($("#meetingRoom"));
                    }

                    function clearForm($form) { 
                      $form.find(':input').val(''); 
                      $form.find(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', false); 
                    }

                });
```

This code is not tested yet, but it should work, let me know if you have any problems.

You should consider to have multiple forms for different uses as your case is... in fact if you use multiple forms you wouldn't need to worry about clearing other form inputs. also you are using the same ID for your inputs in different tabs, but inside the same form.

Comment: your clearForm function was not working until i did it in this way 
`
    function clearForm($form)
                    {
                        $form.find(':input').val('');
                        $form.find(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', false);
                    }
` 
can you tell me why that was not working wiith your logic. 
This is multiple forms but user has to select only one that's why i am clearing previous tabs fields and i didn't get you that you are saying i am using same ID for m inputs in different tabs. elaborate please :)

Comment: the `.not` property was intended to exclude button, submit, reset, hidden, checkbox, and radio, because the property we wanted to clear wasn't value, that's why we do that for checkbox and radio with the property `checked` my mistake was to forget that i'm pointing to a div selector... at least i guess that's why.

About the same ID, is because the ID selector should be Unique in html, that could get you in some troubles if you need to point them specifically.

So at the end you got it working right?  i didn't get if you make it.